# Running Node app via PM2 on port 80

Tags: node.js, web-services, amazon-ec2, port, pm2

I have an express that I want to run on port 80. --> `app.listen(80);`

I'm using `PM2` to manage the app (restarting, stopping, monitoring, etc.) . I have a deployment shell script whose last command is `PM2 restart index`.  From the console output, I see no errors and `PM2` reports that it successfully completed the command.  Yet when I got to `my.ec2.ip.address:80` the site is not up.  Furthermore, if I run `node index.js` in my server project directory, I get a `Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80`.  This makes some sense to me as port 80 is below 1024 and therefore a privileged port.  `sudo node index.js` will allow the launch to work.

I'm a newbie to unix, servers, permissions, and deployment, so in addition to the solution, an explanation of the fundamental concepts contributing to my problem would be greatly appreciated.  For instance.. is it bad to simply run my node app as super-user?  Is it good practice to run `PM2` (therefore possibly running node as..?) root/super-user?  The command `sudo PM2 restart index` leads to `sudo: pm2: command not found`.  Why is `PM2` not found when running `sudo PM2`.. if `PM2` is in my path?

Ultimately though, when using `PM2` how can I ensure that my server runs on port 80?  not found.

Answer (score 17):

Dont use port 80, run on other port like 8080 and redirect 80 to that port with this command

```
  sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Comment: After running this I was able to access http://example.org:80, but http://example.org didn't. To undo this command:
http://lubos.rendek.org/remove-all-iptables-prerouting-nat-rules/

Answer (score 7):

It's good to run as little as possible as a priviliged user, as you want to restrict the potential damage in case someone exploits your program. You don't want to run your Node code as root unless you absolutely have to.

Therefore, it's better to run your Node program on an unprivileged port (say, port 8000), and instead have a lightweight web server such as Nginx listen on port 80 and simply forward traffic to your Node program.

If you want to go with Nginx, you can use this configuration to do exactly what I described above, and then just listen with your Node program on port 3000:

```
server {
  listen 80 default;
  listen [::]:80 default;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, for the ubuntu server.
Fixed with the tutorial below.

```
sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /usr/local/bin/node
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Also here is another solution from PM2

```
sudo apt-get install authbind
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chown %user% /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chmod 755 /etc/authbind/byport/80
```

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/specifics/#listening-on-port-80-w-o-root

## 2024 Update

Even though my answer is correct, I highly recommend using @Frxstrem's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44911388/502649) both flexibility & [security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/principle_of_least_privilege)-wise.
Letting Node to use port 80 is not a wise idea.

You can implement additional security layers with stuff like Nginx. Also can run multiple Node.JS servers sharing port 80 with different URLs.

Answer (score 3):

Though, you may have solved the issue but for the one who comes here facing the same issue, this worked me :

For just troubleshooting, run your app using `sudo npm start`. If your app runs normally then you need to bind port `80` with the help of `authbind` package.  Run these commands :

```
sudo apt-get install authbind
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chown %user% /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chmod 755 /etc/authbind/byport/80
```

Replace `%user%` with the user you run pm2. Mine was `ubuntu` by default.

Set `start` command in your `package.json` file to `pm2 start <server_file_name>`. 
Run the app using `npm start`. It should work !

Answer (score 2):

After lot of time spent configuring nginx, finally uninstall it and followed A.J. suggestion to configure **iptables**. Thank you A.J.

`sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`

But, if anyone know a perfect tutorial to configure nginx, would be a great help.